# Intel Xdk using Crosswalk Cordova hybrid platform build but local widget not working

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins, intel-xdk, crosswalk-runtime

I'm new intel xdk loT edition user. I'm having a problem and feeling lost right now. Hope somebody can help.

I create a mobile app using third party cordova plugin to send message and some local intel xdk widget (geolocation and youtube).My project type(HTML5+cordova),
There was a "*" in the Domain list under Project Settings also.

while I built it through legacy hybrid mobile App platform(Android),the local intel xdk widget (geolocation and youtube) can work but cordova(send message) cant work.

while I built it through cordova hybrid mobile app platform, cordova(send message) can work well but intel xdk widget (geolocation and youtube) become blank.

Comment: have you checked the intel.xdk plugins in the plugin settings

Comment: There have been some problems with AJAX calls on some Android 4.4 and 5.0 devices when using the CLI 4.1.2 build. Try building with Cordova CLI 3.5 and see if the widgets work then.

Comment: @xmnboy Thanks for answer my question, i try built using CLI 3.5 crosswalk android, but that map cant work also. Actually, I build my app by applying the AR map sample map [link](https://software.intel.com/en-us/html5/articles/augmented-reality-mobile-app-with-html5). It working well while i build it in legacy android but not working in crosswalk. I'm curious @.@

Comment: I'll see if the creator of that sample app can take a closer look. I see there are several comments on the article for the app that also indicate problems. It may simply need to be updated. -- In the meantime, there are several other samples that incorporate maps, try those to see how to get a map to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem solved with new update of Intel Xdk software with allow to add access list which Whitelist : internal.

1. press + Add Another Access List Entry
2. Just add * in the text box
3. and choose internal

[image]